# PHP code in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have this HTML code in `signature_html` column in `table user_signature`

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><span style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 0.5em; font-weight: bold;">John Doe</span></p>
<div style="font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.1em; padding-bottom: 15px;">
  Sales Officer<a href="<?php echo $result; ?>"></a><br />
  Tel:   +123456<br />
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

I want to get the value of `Sales Officer` from `Mysql`, something like this:

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><span style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 0.5em; font-weight: bold;">John Doe</span></p>
<div style="font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.1em; padding-bottom: 15px;">
  <?php
    $username="foo";
    $password="abc123";
    $host="1.2.3.4";
    $database="abcd1234";
    $con = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
    @mysql_select_db($database);
    $query=select description from users where id = "ea875d10-385e-973c-ce5a-5dec1bdd126";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    mysql_close($con);
  ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $result; ?>"></a><br />
  Tel: +123456<br />
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

To make it more clear: I have this table in Mysql DB which contains these fields:

```
mysql> desc users_signatures;

id
date_entered
date_modified
user_id
signature_html
```

In the field signature_html I have the above coded HTML (directly in the DB table field). Therefore I wanted to embed PHP code in the DB table field; directly.

I have tried this and it doesn't work.

```
UPDATE users_signatures SET signature_html='<p>&nbsp;</p>\r\n<table style=\"margin: 0px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; color: #444444; font-family: helvetica, arial; width: 600px; background-color: #ffffff;\" border=\"0\"  cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"10\">\r\n<tbody>\r\n<tr>\r\n<td><span style=\"font-size: 14px; line-height: 0.5em; font-weight: bold;\">John Doe</span><br />\r\n<div style=\"font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.1em; padding-bottom: 15px;\"><?php $description="Sales Officer"; ?><a href="<?php echo $description; ?>"></a><br /><br /> Tel: +123456</div>\r\n</td>\r\n<td>&nbsp;</td>\r\n</tr>\r\n</tbody>\r\n</table>' WHERE id = '828f7724-2ee9-7ae9-cfb5-55e69e650eef' AND deleted=0;
```

Comment: You should enclose properly the content of your `$query` variable: `$query = "SELECT description FROM users WHERE id = 'ea875d10-385e-973c-ce5a-5dec1bdd126'";`

Comment: Fetch the appropriate value from `$result` and then echo that.

Answer (score 1):

You should enclose properly the content of your `$query` variable:

```
$query = "SELECT description FROM users WHERE id = 'ea875d10-385e-973c-ce5a-5dec1bdd126'";
```

You should also refrain from using `mysql_*` API as this is [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) already.

Fetch also the result to output them.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $description = $row["description"];
}
```

But, you should consider using `mysqli_*` [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead:

```
...
    /* ESTABLISH CONNECTION */
    $con = new mysqli("1.2.3.4", "foo", "abc123", "abcd1234");

    if($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT `description` FROM users WHERE id = 'ea875d10-385e-973c-ce5a-5dec1bdd126'")){ /* CHECK IF THE QUERY IS TRUE */
      $stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE QUERY */
      $stmt->bind_result($description); /* BIND THE RESULT TO THIS VARIABLE */
      $stmt->fetch(); /* FETCH THE RESULT */
      $stmt->close(); /* CLOSE THE PREPARED STATEMENT */
    }
  ?>
<a href="<?php echo $description; ?>"><?php echo $description; ?></a><br />
```

Comment: Actually the above HTML code I've pasted are the contents of a column in a table. So I wanted to know if I can include PHP code in the column contents to fetch the value from the same DB. There is no external PHP file here.

Comment: What do you mean? Please elaborate it in your post.

Comment: @asvasdvasdvsadvs - you want to fetch a data from `users` table then put it on a `<a>...</a>`? Correct me if I'm wrong. If yes, then you can just adapt the answer I gave to you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you want to save a piece of php code (a partial template) in a table column, and retrieve *and* execute it whenever needed. Right?

However this is possible, using the [`eval()`](http://php.net/eval) function, this is actually bad practice. In your specific case it is quite ridiculous actually, because you are querying the database, which returns code, that will query the same database... Sounds like the mailman bringing you a message which says that the mailman will bring you a message. Ha!

Best practice would be to save the atomary data in the database, or save a kind of a template in the database. Eg:

```
...
<a href="{{url}}">{{description}}</a>
...
```

Now retrieve the `url` and `description`, on whatever way you retrieve data from the database, and replace the strings in the template:

```
$template = str_replace(array('{{url}}', '{{description}}', array($url, $description), $template);
```

And now do with the template however you want it.

It's a really simple example, but it'll work.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible, but is not a good practice to connect to mysql from an inline query. You should create a db-connect.php file and use require_once('db-connect.php') for that file and then jus use the $connection variable to run your query.

Be aware that $result may return an array that must be parsed with a while if your statement returns multiple results.